# PostgreSQL returning JSON array containing null value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have the following query on PostgreSQL, I have the vacations columns that I display an array of objects, but some columns don't have values and will return null values, but the problem is, it will always return a array that looks like `[NULL]`, Is it possible to return only an empty `[]`?

```
SELECT 
    u."name",
    u.email,
    to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(uv))) as vacations
from public."user" as u 
join user_address ua on ua.user_id = u.id 
left join user_vacation uv on uv.address_id = ua.id 
where u.place is not null 
group by 
    u."name",
    u.email;
```

Result:

```
name       | email            | vacations
some_name  | some@email.com   | [{"id": 1, "area": "description"}]
some_name  | some@email.com   | [{"id": 1, "area": "description"}]
some_name  | some@email.com   | [null]
some_name  | some@email.com   | [null]
```

Comment: sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `count(right-table.column)` to check if right table has matching rows or not; and build a case expression that returns `[]` or `[{...}, {...}]` depending on the count.

That being said, I would rather re-write your query like so:

```
select *, coalesce((
    select json_agg(row_to_json(user_vacation))
    from user_address
    join user_vacation on user_address.id = user_vacation.address_id
    where user_address.user_id = "user".id
), '[]') as vacations
from "user"
where place is not null
```

Comment: Wouldn't a left join on an aggregate sub-query be tidier than a correlated sub-query?

Comment: Tidier is opinion based but it'll work too, yes.